# Converting from Double to float for android canvas

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to convert from the type Double to the type float. I have this:

```
Double doubleValue = new Double( result[0].X() );
canvas.drawCircle( doubleValue.floatValue(), doubleValue.floatValue(), ... );
```

result is an array of Point. For some reason, the value in result[0].X() is equal to 128.0, but when I do the floatValue() I get -100.0 instead.

What would be the proper way of converting from the primitive type Double to float?

Comment: If `result[0].X` really is equal to `128.0`, then `doubleValue.floatValue()` will be equal to `128.0` too. So it is likely that `result[0].X` is not what you think it is.

Comment: pint out the doubleValue or result to the screen so you can confirm what it is

Comment: Is there some reason you're not just doing "float v = (float)result[0].X;" ?

Comment: I also facing similar issue...n it ask to convert values like 1623197.960938,-1663247.460938 in float, which not be same after conversion, how can retain values while drawing...any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the float value is correct (verified with debug). But the drawCircle won't draw it at the specified position... which is an entire different problem. Thanks all.

Comment: Double is not a primitive data type.  "double" is.  Do you have reason to use Double?  That said, your circle (drawCircle works just fine) not being where you expect it to be is another thing altogether.  floatValue() is also totally reliable.  These things have been in Java for years and are thoroughly tested/debugged.

Comment: The only reason why I used Double was because I created a Point class which is templated.